# Can Visual Studio's Git Changes window open the actual file and not a temp version?

Tags: git, visual-studio

Whether I have a solution open (that contains the file) or not and am looking at the Git Changes history, when perform the following steps:

1. Double click on a commit to open the details window (opening the
   Changes window containing the files changed).
2. Right click on a file and select Open from the context menu.

Visual Studio opens a temp file with the contents of the file. I could have sworn that if the file was in the open solution it would open the actual file and not a temp version.

My questions are:

1. Did something change in Visual Studio?
2. Is there a way to have Visual Studio open the actual file instead of temp if it is in the open solution (again I feel like this was recent behavior until lately). I don't use Visual Studio git window except for a few things and this is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is, what does "the file" mean?

Git works off "revisions", of files and of your project as a whole. A commit is of specific revisions. When you add a new revision, it gets added to the repo and the index gets updated to point to the added revision. Then you can change "the file" in your work tree some more, maybe see if you can improve on what you added, so now there's *three* revisions of "the file" in very easy reach: the one in your work tree, the one in your HEAD commit (which the standard convenience commands maintain as the last revision you checked out or committed, or otherwise told Git is what your current checkout is based on), and the one listed in your index which is the last revision you checked out *or added*.

So when you pick a path out of a commit and ask to see it, GUI frontends will treat that as a request to see the committed revision, which is not necessarily the same as either the staged aka indexed aka last-added revision or whatever version is currently in your work tree -- and since you're in an IDE none of those necessarily match what's your editor's got buffered for that path.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. My meaning is I can see the location in the file system inside the git changes window.  I thought that there was a way to open the file from there based on its location in the file system and if the file was part of the currently opened solution, Visual Studio would open that (instead of the temp file of the revision).

Comment: It'd be a pretty easy editor macro in any programmer's editor I know, check for a buffer with that path, `git hash-object`  the contents, check that against the committed hash. Or even easier just preemptively find that path in the work tree without checking whether its contents differ from the committed revision. That's just the start of the corner cases here, there's going to be a lot of different rulesets for resolving them,  "wrong" for different use cases. Then it'd be how do it without confusing people who don't understand the extensible dag of immutable snapshots nature of Git history